# If mass and energy can neither be created nor be destroyed then how in nuclear fusion mass is converted to energy with the formula $E = mc^2$?

Tags: mass, energy-conservation, nuclear-physics, mass-energy

It is said by law of conservation of mass and energy that:

> Mass and energy can neither be created nor be destroyed.

But if it is true then during a nuclear fusion or fission reaction how is mass converted to energy. In this case the mass is being reduced and energy is being increased. I know that it is due to the equation $E= mc^2$.

**But does this violate the above quote?**

Comment: *It is said…* By whom, where?

Comment: By conservation laws

Comment: Mass is now known not to be conserved. You have given an example of that. A more extreme case is that two massive particles, such as an electron and a positron, can annihilate into two photons, neither of which has mass. And vice versa. The invariant mass of the entire system *is* conserved,  but the sum of the invariant masses of the individual particles is *not* conserved.

Comment: In Valoruz's defence most high school physics books do say the same thing without much elaboration.

Comment: It is said that the universe is about 6000 years old.  Yet the universe is billions of years old.  However could one reconcile these things?

Answer (score 1):

"Mass is converted to energy" is a widespread but sloppy and misleading expression. Mass is a different concept than energy and there is no conversion.

More correctly, "mass energy" or "rest energy" is converted to "useful" energy, such as heat and radiation. These go away from the materials, so both rest energy and mass of the remaining materials decreases a little, in accordance with the Einstein relation
$$
\Delta m = \frac{\Delta E}{c^2}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Mass is *not* conserved in general, and neither is energy. What is conserved is mass-energy. You're seeing it in action in nuclear fusion/fission - as you write, "the mass is being reduced and energy is being increased". The energy increases by exactly the amount of mass lost, converted using $E = mc^2$.

Comment: This is incorrect - energy is conserved, because rest energy due to mass was already there. Energy does not increase, it only transforms from one form (potential energy) into another form (heat and radiation).

Answer (score -1):

When two nuclei of light merge they form energy. The mass and energy is not destroyed as it is like saying reduced water turning into steam violates the conservation of energy.

*deuterium + tritium → energy*

This is *universal* and the law of conservation of matter and energy is not violated in all these processes:

Virtual particles are off mass shell, they do not satisfy the equations of motion, they are physically *not real* and are only in the calculations of perturbation theory hence virtual. No violation of energy, it doesn't exist.

*e*$^2$ - ⎪*p*⎪$^2$c$^2$ ≠ m$^2$c$^2$

When matter and antimatter annihilate all of the energy is transferred to the gamma rays photons. So energy is consevered.

*e$^-$* + *e$^+$* → .

In the case of destructive inference of light it is often argued and claimed that the energy is compensated through the regions of constructive interference.

Destructive region → Constructive region

The *only way* you can destroy energy that I know of at least is through the *physics of active noise cancellation* where energy can be destroyed. Two sounds that are the exact mirror image/inverse of each other cancel out, simply disappearing into silence. (no energy release, not off shell, just a conversion into utter silence).

*Noise + Noise (reversed/mirrored) → Silence* ✓

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).